# How predict next word using LSTM model?

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I am currently building an LSTM model in Pytorch to predict the next word of a given input.

My model:

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, dropout_rate, tie_weights):
    super().__init__()

    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
    self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim

    self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers=num_layers, 
                    dropout=dropout_rate, batch_first=True)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_rate)
    self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, vocab_size)

    if tie_weights:
      #Embedding and hidden layer need to be same size for weight tieing
          assert embedding_dim == hidden_dim, 'cannot tie, check dims'
          self.linear.weight = self.embedding.weight
    self.init_weights()

  def forward(self, x):
    # x is a batch of input sequences
    x = self.embedding(x)
    x, _ = self.lstm(x)
    x = self.linear(x)
    return x

  def init_weights(self):
    init_range_emb = 0.1
    init_range_other = 1/math.sqrt(self.hidden_dim)
    self.embedding.weight.data.uniform_(-init_range_emb, init_range_emb)
    self.linear.weight.data.uniform_(-init_range_other, init_range_other)
    self.linear.bias.data.zero_()
    for i in range(self.num_layers):
        self.lstm.all_weights[i][0] = torch.FloatTensor(self.embedding_dim,
                self.hidden_dim).uniform_(-init_range_other, init_range_other) 
        self.lstm.all_weights[i][1] = torch.FloatTensor(self.hidden_dim, 
                self.hidden_dim).uniform_(-init_range_other, init_range_other)



vocab_size = len(vocab)
embedding_dim = 100
hidden_dim = 100
num_layers = 2
dropout_rate = 0.4
tie_weights = True
model = LSTM(vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, dropout_rate, tie_weights)
model.to(device)
```

Training and evaluation funciton:

```
import copy
import time

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
lr = 20.0  # learning rate
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, 1.0, gamma=0.95)

def train(model: nn.Module) -> None:
    model.train()  # turn on train mode
    total_loss = 0.
    log_interval = 200
    start_time = time.time()
    
    num_batches = len(train_data) // bptt
    for batch, i in enumerate(range(0, train_data.size(0) - 1, bptt)):
        data, targets = get_batch(train_data, i)
        seq_len = data.size(0)
        output = model(data)
        loss = criterion(output.view(-1, vocab_size), targets)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 0.5)
        optimizer.step()

        total_loss += loss.item()
        
        if batch % log_interval == 0 and batch > 0:
            lr = scheduler.get_last_lr()[0]
            ms_per_batch = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000 / log_interval
            cur_loss = total_loss / log_interval
            ppl = math.exp(cur_loss)
            print(f'| epoch {epoch:3d} | {batch:5d}/{num_batches:5d} batches | '
                  f'lr {lr:02.2f} | ms/batch {ms_per_batch:5.2f} | '
                  f'loss {cur_loss:5.2f} | ppl {ppl:8.2f}')
            total_loss = 0
            start_time = time.time()


def evaluate(model: nn.Module, eval_data: Tensor) -> float:
    model.eval()  # turn on evaluation mode
    total_loss = 0.
    with torch.no_grad():
        for i in range(0, eval_data.size(0) - 1, bptt):
            data, targets = get_batch(eval_data, i)
            seq_len = data.size(0)
            output = model(data)
            output_flat = output.view(-1, vocab_size)
            total_loss += seq_len * criterion(output_flat, targets).item()
    return total_loss / (len(eval_data) - 1)
```

Training loop

```
best_val_loss = float('inf')
epochs = 50
best_model = None

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    epoch_start_time = time.time()
    train(model)
    val_loss = evaluate(model, val_data)
    val_ppl = math.exp(val_loss)
    elapsed = time.time() - epoch_start_time
    print('-' * 89)
    print(f'| end of epoch {epoch:3d} | time: {elapsed:5.2f}s | '
          f'valid loss {val_loss:5.2f} | valid ppl {val_ppl:8.2f}')
    print('-' * 89)

    if val_loss < best_val_loss:
        best_val_loss = val_loss
        best_model = copy.deepcopy(model)

    scheduler.step()
```

My problem is I have no idea how to go about this. I've seen some implementations of character based LSTM text generators but I'm looking for it to be word based. For example I want to pass an input like "How are you" and the output will included the next predicted word, like for example "How are you today"

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try the example in the attached link(https://www.kaggle.com/code/ysthehurricane/next-word-prediction-bi-lstm-tutorial-easy-way).

You can download the dataset from the attached link below.
(https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/dorianlazar/medium-articles-dataset)

It tries to predict the next word using Bi-directional LSTM architecture. I think that this example mostly suits to your needs, which will give you an idea to proceed further.

You can follow the instruction provided in the first link.